# How to show a video on a web page using Python?

Tags: python, html, flash, video, web

To show an image on a web page I need to use `<img>` tag in the HTML code and in this tag to "point" to an image file location on my web-server. Can display video in a similar way? I just use a tag (for example `<video>`) and within this tag I point to `avi` or `mp4` file located on my web-server.

I suppose that it cannot be done in the above described simple way. So, if it is the case, how can it be done?

I need to notice that I do not want to use videos provided by youtube or other web-services. I want to have a site where user can submit videos (for example as mp4 or avi files) and the site should be able to show these videos to other users.

Does it mean that I need to be able to convert avi and mp4 files into a flash-format? Can Python do it? Should I use HTML5 functionality instead of flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is w3school's info on HTML5 video.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) Fortunately it's shockingly easy, and if you know how to add a picture with python, doing what you want with html5 video is not at all a great next step.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```